# After Enlightenment - 7 Weeks (Sath Sathiya)

Tags: pali-canon, enlightenment, buddha

As we all have heard the Buddha spent 7 weeks after his enlightenment in different places and engaging in different activities.

But in the Mahavagga Pali (the first half) in Vinaya Pitakaya states that the Buddha only spent 4 weeks after enlightenment. And after that week only the Sahampati Brhama invited him to teach Dhamma to the world. (In the 7 weeks tradition this happened in the 7th week)

1st Week  - Under the Bodhi tree

2nd Week  - Under the Ajhapal Nuga(Goatherds’Banyan tree) tree

3rd Week  - Under the Midhella tree (The Mucalinda story)

4th Week  - Under the Kiripalu tree (The Tapssu Balluka story)

Also in the Sutra Pitakaya I found the following sutras as well.

These sutras talks about the first week.
[Ud1.1](https://suttacentral.net/en/ud1.1)
[Ud1.2](https://suttacentral.net/en/ud1.2)
[Ud1.3](https://suttacentral.net/en/ud1.3)

This sutra talks about the second week.
[Ud1.4](https://suttacentral.net/en/ud1.4)

This sutra talks about the third week
[Ud2.1](https://suttacentral.net/en/ud2.1)

4th week is anyways stated in the Mahavagga Pali.

But in the Pujawaliya written by Ven. Mayurapada Parivenadhipathi Buddhaputhra suggests that the Buddha spent 7 weeks after the enlightnment in different places and engaging in different activities. [Sath Sathiya - 7 Weeks](http://archives.sundayobserver.lk/2006/05/14/jun07.asp)

If Vinaya Pitakaya is the one that is to be accepted (Vinaya and Dhamma are the Teachers after me - Buddha) then did the Pujawaliya writer exaggerate the 4 weeks into 7 weeks? Even in that book i didn't find any references to the Tripitakaya (Pali Canon) as well.

Comment: Very timely with all the interest around Pujawaliya in the radio and media.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a possibility that Buddha stayed in Uruvela forest more than four(4) weeks. It was mentioned in **Mahavagga Pali, section 6, end of paragraph 10** but it did not specify exactly 3 weeks more or places of additional weeks. The last line of that paragraph [here](http://archive.org/stream/bookofdiscipline14hornuoft/bookofdiscipline14hornuoft_djvu.txt)

[image: ][1]]

did mention Buddha stayed more than four(4) weeks probably made the best timing for five foremost monks for first discourse.

If found about this more details in any sutta, I'll update here.

Comment: The additional information might be in the commentaries?

Comment: But him staying 4 weeks there and taking 4 weeks more to travel to Isipathana by foot seems legit. There's around 200-300 KM on the way. So taking a month to go there is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Mahavagga Paliya, Kahnadaka clearly says Buddha stayed 5 weeks (not 4) after enlightenment.

1. First week - Under the Bo-tree. Templating on Patichchasamuppada. (Chain of causation)
2. Second week - Under Ajapal banyan tree. Meeting a brahamin
3. Third week - Under the cover of Muchalinda, the serpent.
4. Forth week - Under the Rajayatana tree. Meeting two merchants
5. Fifth week - Again under Ajapal banyan tree. Meeting Sahampathi brahma